# Как сервера обмениваются файлами, картинками?

Tags: php, javascript

Как сервера обмениваются файлами, к примеру картинки, как передают картинки? В виде текст их зачитывает и передает, или как?

Какими способами это сделать я знаю, просто интересно как это происходит

Comment: точно так же, как ваш браузер скачивает с сервера данные.
вы запрашиваете данные по ссылке, сервер передает вам тип данных (картинка!)  в заголовке http, соответственно, вы знаете, что раз это картинка, а не текст, то положить ее надо  в папку с картинками, а не записать в  бд, допустим.  если не передавать mime type, можно просто взять сырые данные и куда-нибудь их слить. серверу пофиг, картинка это или текст. получил байты, сохранил/переслал байты/сообщил об ошибке. почитайте про протокол http

Comment: Файлы передаются в байтах, с текстовыми заголовками. Более подробно можно почитать даже тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP не считая документации.

Comment: Ещё вариант - через базу данных.

Comment: То есть, как я понял даже если и картинка - она преобразуется в "текст" и передается, а по типу уже определяется что это картинка?

Comment: В smtp протоколе картинки перегоняют в Base64. А потом декодируют. А так смотря как сервера написаны. Могу открыть соединение и передавать группами байт. Могу опять же декодировать в строку.